# Scala complex type

Tags: arrays, scala

I work with Scala. I define the following function

```
scala> def getEdgesMortages( fila: Array[((org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId,
ComplaintNodeDate),(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, MortageNode))]): 
Array[String] = {
 | println("row ",fila)
 | println("row 0 ",fila(0))
 | var (idVertice, datoComplaint) = fila(0)
 | println("idVertice ",idVertice)
 | var z = Array("z")
 | return z
 | }
getEdgesMortages: (fila: Array[((org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId,  
ComplaintNodeDate), (org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId,
MortageNode))])Array[String]
```

I executed this function with the values

```
 scala>getEdgesMortages(Array(((101,ComplaintLoan("01/22/2014","Mortgage","Conventional 
fixed mortgage",
"Web","Closed with explanation")),
(501,MortageData("Refinancing","Application denied by financial 
institution",
"One-to-four family dwelling (other than manufactured housing)")))))
```

Exit messages are

```
(row ,[Lscala.Tuple2;@29f6dc76)
(row 0 ,((101,ComplaintLoan(01/22/2014,Mortgage,Conventional fixed   
mortgage,Web,Closed with explanation)),
(501,MortageData(Refinancing,Application denied by financial    
institution,One-to-four family dwelling (other than manufactured 
 housing)))))
(idVertice ,(101,ComplaintLoan(01/22/2014,Mortgage,Conventional fixed 
mortgage,Web,Closed with explanation)))
res55: Array[String] = Array(z)
```

I have to extract the value 101 of

```
((101,ComplaintLoan(01/22/2014,Mortgage,Conventional fixed    
  mortgage,Web,Closed with explanation)),
```

This is the element with index 0 of array fila.

How can I extract value 101?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something foo._1, where `foo` holds "the element with index 0 of array fila.". That's a tuple, and accessing the elements of a tuple is done with ._1, ._2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can access tuples values using `_<idx>`, where `idx` is one-based. e.g.:

```
scala> val t = (1,2,3)
t: (Int, Int, Int) = (1,2,3)

scala> t._1
res0: Int = 1
```

So in your case something like `element._1._1` should work.

Keep in mind that returning tuples from functions is usually considered bad practice, have you considered creating an ad-hoc [case class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) instead?